# Tensorflow source for autogenerated python modules from C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, bazel

Very often I want to check the source code for some tensorflow module. Usually, a a large part of the API is written in native python and the relevant file is easy to find on github. However, there are some important parts that I are written in C++ and I cannot find the source code for them. For example, according to the official TensorFlow documentation, most of the math ops are defined in `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py`. However, there is no such file on GitHub. My local installation of TF has this file, but checking the source on GitHub is much easier. I also want to understand where should I search for the rules which specify how a python file is generated. I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am not familiar with bazel.

Comment: I believe you can find the C++ source for gen files in `core`. So for `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py`,  you can find the C++ source at  `tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc`. I'm not sure about the rules for generating files, so I've added this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I also want to understand where should I search for the rules which specify how a python file is generated.

Use `bazel query` for this.

If you want to know which rule generates a file (e.g. `$PROJECT/some/dir/file.py`), run this command from the project root:

`bazel query --output=build some/dir/file.py`

For example, if I want to find out which rule generates a particular `jar` file, `bazel query` prints this:

```
$ bazel query --output=build examples/java-native/src/test/java/com/example/myproject/hello.jar
# /Users/foo/bazel/examples/java-native/src/test/java/com/example/myproject/BUILD:1:1
java_test(
  name = "hello",
  deps = ["//examples/java-native/src/main/java/com/example/myproject:hello-lib", "//third_party:junit4"],
  srcs = ["//examples/java-native/src/test/java/com/example/myproject:TestHello.java"],
  test_class = "com.example.myproject.TestHello",
)
```

Check out the [Query how-to documentation page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html#what-files-are-generated-by-rules-in-the-foo-package) for more `bazel query` tips.